# Error: Could not create output file Processed 0 frames

Tags: intel-oneapi, onevpl

I am running one of the oneVPL samples- hello-vpp.
I've downloaded the samples source code from oneAPI samples repository-

https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneAPI-samples.git

My OS is Ubuntu 18.04.
After build, I tried the below command to get the output.
`./hello-vpp ../content/input.i420 640 480`
and I got the below error.

```
Could not create output file
Processed 0 frames
```

Any corrections in my command? What would be the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VPP sample only works with i420 video format and it's size must be 128x96. So the right command to run hello-vpp sample is:

```
./hello-vpp ../content/input.i420 128x96
```

The expected output would be

```
Found ApiVersion: 2.2          
SW   session created
Processing ../content/input.i420 -> out.i420
Processed 60 frames
```

The output file i.e. out.i420 would be found in the build directory(Path: "\Libraries\oneVPL\hello-vpp\build")  and its size is 640x480 by default.